# I cant install Flask

Tags: python, flask, pip

I am trying to install flask but everytime i get this error 
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'`. I have added python to path and have even reinstalled it but it just isnt working. I followed steps of activating virtual environment and using `pip install flask` but it still doesn't seem to work. I need to get my a level coursework completed in a week! Please help.

Comment: If you use a virtual environment to `pip install`, you must run your python program in the same environment to use those packages.  You haven't provided enough information here for someone else to know what you're doing incorrectly

Comment: maybe you have two Pythons installed and `pip` install it for one Python but later you run second Python - you can try `python -m pip install ...`

Comment: are you sure you are using the virtualenv pip? the one in <virtualenv_folder>/bin/pip
Oh and what give you the error, can you screen or copy paste the command failing?

Answer (score 2):

To check if you have actually installed flask, try this command:`pip freeze` then check if it is actually listed. 
Normal procedure to start a flask app would be:
- create a virtual environment.Make sure you are using python 3. check by using this command. `python --version`. It should print out the latest version.
- Install Flask. For good measure you could use pip3 to make sure you are using python3.

```
pip3 install Flask
```

- Run your app.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what OS you're using, so I'll make a recommendation for you that's pretty easy to set up on the majority of OS's/Distros:

If you're really in a pinch use [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/).

I find Conda (Anaconda) quite nice for managing python pip environments.
Get it working in your operating system, then `pip install Flask` in a new Conda environment. [This is a useful cheatsheet for Conda.](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) 
Once you've activated the environment for your Flask project development should be a breeze.

Good luck.